# Drag attachments from outlook to sharepoint?

Tags: outlook, attachments

Does Sharepoint have any integration with Outlook where I can simply drag and drop e-mail attachments in to a Sharepoint library?

It looks like "Harmon.ie" does it but the company is unwilling to purchase the 3rd party software

Currently we are using 2010, have the features added since?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below steps and see if that's works.

- Open your SharePoint site
- Select the Document Library to store the file
- Select the "Explorer View" of the Document Library
- Now open Outlook
- Open the Email with the attachment
- Resize Outlook so you can see the explorer view of the document
  library
- Click on the attachment and drag to the folder area of the explorer
  view

[source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/387de33a-80c7-4d21-9eef-56ce16d8a935/unable-to-drag-attachments-from-outlook-to-sharepoint-https-site?forum=sharepointadminlegacy)

But latest version of SharePoint you have better options.

Comment: Thanks, not ideal though as would like to be able to do it from outlook direc.t

Comment: Thanks. Not ideal though as I'd like to do it from outlook direct. Are you able to tell me what these better options are with the latest versions of sharepoint? 2013 and 2016?

Answer (score 0):

Direct drag and drop functionality is not possible with a normal Document Library.

So use a **Discussion Board** List instead and link it to your Outlook (List Options **Connect to Outlook**). This will allow you to simply drag and drop E-Mails or just Attachments inside Outlook to the linked "Discussion Board" List.

Answer (score 0):

you can add one Add-ins in Outlook **harmon.ie**, which is providing support to outlook attachment to save into SharePoint document library. Please refer screen shot - right hand side one option is available after adding the add-ins (Save to SharePoint) [image]